# How to remove tips box with Wacom tablet in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-tablet

HP Envy TS15 Laptop running 64 bit Windows with Wacom Intuos Pen Tablet small (CTL-480).

All was fine. Suddenly, I started getting little yellow tool tip boxes whenever any of the following keys are touched: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or combination).

This only happens when using the pen with the tablet. Touchpad or mouse doesn't cause it to happen.  Solution on this site for Windows 8 doesn't work.  Wacom blame Microsoft.

Comment: What site, and what did it say?